# Force using keyboard shortcuts to Catalyst iPad application

Tags: macos, ipad, mac-catalyst

This might feel weird, but I recently bought an M2 Pro, and I've started messing around iPad apps that could run on my mac. However, there are no keybindings for these apps, as far as I can see.

Is there a way to force keyboard shortcuts for Catalyst apps?

Note that these are **not opensource**, so no luck with any code. Moreover, playing with AppleScript didn't bring me any hints...

Comment: https://osxdaily.com/2017/08/08/create-custom-keyboard-shortcut-mac/

Comment: @SwiftIsGreat unfortunately this is an iPad app, it does not have menus. I would need to map it to a screen location click.

Comment: did you try using third-party app like Keyboard Maestro or BetterTouchTool, which allows you to create custom keyboard shortcuts for any app?

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a custom shortcut using the macOS System Preferences. After creating your shortcut, it should be available in the Catalyst app's menu and you can use the keyboard combination you assigned to activate it.